# Multiplying all the values from a dataframe by a single column from another dataframe and save the results in a new object

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a time-series in R from the population reduction of tree species from 2000–2019. To do this, I'm using two data frames: 1) species relative density per site and 2) numbers of trees per site (same sites as before), something like:

```
#creating a table of years x site, where the values are the number of trees per site
year1 = c(1122, 1134, 1114)
year2 = c(1115, 11165, 1170)
year3 = c(1162, 1110, 1111)
year_site <- data.frame(year1, year2, year3)


#creating a table of species x site (the same number and order of sites as before),
#where the values are relative density per site
sp1 = c(0.50, 0.1, 0.01)
sp2 = c(0.25, 0.15, 0.10)
sp3 = c(0.005, 0.005, 0.045)
sp4 = c(0.060, 0.00035, 0.01)
sp5 = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.4)
sp_site <- data.frame(sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5)
```

So, I want to

1. multiply the `sp_site` dataframe by each vector of `year_site` separately,
2. `sum` the values of each `sp_site$sp[i]` and then
3. save the summed values of each species for each year in a new object

I'm trying to use `for` loops but I'm unable to proceed. It was something like:

```
#creating a list() to save the results
sp_list <- setNames(vector('list', length(sp_site)), sp_site)

for (y in names(year_site)){
  for (sp in names(sp_site)){
    out <- sum(year_site[,y]*sp_site[, sp])
    sp_list[[sp]] <- out 
  }
}
```

The code above only loops one year for each species, but I need all the years saved, continually.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: For the first iteration `year_site[, 1]` and `sp_site[, 1]` are of different lengths. How do you want to multiply them? Do you want to multiply row of `year_site` with column of `sp_site` instead? Can you show your final expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Like many problems this one can be more easily solved if you think critically about the way you are storing your data. In particular, what are the shared attributes (or keys) between the two data.frames. This appears to be site number and year... If you restructure your data appropriately, the solution should be trivial.... As written, the question is not clear enough for readers to provide a clear solution.

Comment: Sorry about that, guys. I wrote incorrectly the length. They are the same (3) in both tables. What differs is the number of years/species, but the sites (rows) are the same. 

@RonakShah: I have 695 species and 20 years. My expected output is a dataframe of 20 columns and 695 species. The values should be year_site*sp_site (number of trees x relative density) for each one of the 20 year columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to get the sum of number of trees in each site (tree density x tree per site) within species. I modified your code to get this. Below are some notes about what I changed. 1) your `year_site` has 4 rows (site) which is different with number of rows in `sp_site`. I changed it to 3 to match with `sp_site`; 2) in your for loop I believe the `sp_list[, sp]` meant `sp_site[, sp]`; 3) it seems you did not use the list names you created in sp_list and i just used an empty list to storage the output. Hopefully this solves your problem.

```
year1 = c(1122, 1134, 1114)
year2 = c(1115, 11165, 1170)
year3 = c(1162, 1110, 1111)
year_site <- data.frame(year1, year2, year3)

sp1 = c(0.50, 0.1, 0.01)
sp2 = c(0.25, 0.15, 0.10)
sp3 = c(0.005, 0.005, 0.045)
sp4 = c(0.060, 0.00035, 0.01)
sp5 = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.4)
sp_site <- data.frame(sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5)

sp_list <- list()

for (y in names(year_site)){
  for (sp in names(sp_site)){
    Sum_nTreebySp <- sum(year_site[,y]*sp_site[, sp])
    sp_list[[sp]] <- Sum_nTreebySp 
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
Based on your description, I edited the code for you. Note that I created a matrix `output`to storage your results rather than a list. You can easily convert it to dataframe (`as.data.frame()`) if you want. Let me know if this is what you need.

```
# year_site and sp_site are same as before

output <- matrix(0, dim(sp_site)[2], dim(year_site)[1])
colnames(output) <- names(year_site)
rownames(output) <- names(sp_site)

for (y in names(year_site)){
  for (sp in names(sp_site)){
    Sum_nTreebySp <- sum(year_site[, y] * sp_site[, sp])
    output[sp, y] <- Sum_nTreebySp 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help. Yes, I did write incorrectly the number of elements in each vector/the loop. I corrected it now. The way you approached the loop is the same as I did, however, that only applies to one of the years. It returns a list with 1 column. I wanted to return a list with one column per year. Is it easier to understand now? And thank you again

Comment: See my edit above based on your description. @hiperhiper